# CURL request using DELETE method in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, delete, methods, curl-request

I am trying to call a curl request for delete method using  **Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl.php**.

In this class makeRequest method is responsible for sending curl request. But as I can see that this method is protected so I can't call it directly.

**makeRequest method in Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl.php**

```
/**
 * Make request
 * @param string $method
 * @param string $uri
 * @param array $params
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = [])
{
    $this->_ch = curl_init();
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    } elseif ($method == "GET") {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    } else {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }

    if (count($this->_headers)) {
        $heads = [];
        foreach ($this->_headers as $k => $v) {
            $heads[] = $k . ': ' . $v;
        }
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $heads);
    }

    if (count($this->_cookies)) {
        $cookies = [];
        foreach ($this->_cookies as $k => $v) {
            $cookies[] = "{$k}={$v}";
        }
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(";", $cookies));
    }

    if ($this->_timeout) {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->_timeout);
    }

    if ($this->_port != 80) {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_PORT, $this->_port);
    }

    //$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, [$this, 'parseHeaders']);

    if (count($this->_curlUserOptions)) {
        foreach ($this->_curlUserOptions as $k => $v) {
            $this->curlOption($k, $v);
        }
    }

    $this->_headerCount = 0;
    $this->_responseHeaders = [];
    $this->_responseBody = curl_exec($this->_ch);
    $err = curl_errno($this->_ch);
    if ($err) {
        $this->doError(curl_error($this->_ch));
    }
    curl_close($this->_ch);
}
```

I have to call one of public method of this class which is calling makeRequest method. 
When I check this I can see 2 public methods for **GET** and **POST** request which are calling protected method makeRequest. No other method for **DELETE** which is calling method makeRequest.

```
/**
 * Make GET request
 *
 * @param string $uri uri relative to host, ex. "/index.php"
 * @return void
 */
public function get($uri)
{
    $this->makeRequest("GET", $uri);
}

/**
 * Make POST request
 *
 * @param string $uri
 * @param array $params
 * @return void
 *
 * @see \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client#post($uri, $params)
 */
public function post($uri, $params)
{
    $this->makeRequest("POST", $uri, $params);
}
```

Now my question is that how can I solve my problem or is this bug in magento 2.1.7 or may be I am getting incorrectly. Please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

**class reference**  [curl.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use this object instead:

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
```

Then set the method to

```
$request->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_DELETE);
```

For more information, read the tutorial in the following link:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/gs-web-api-request.html

Comment: hello @Toan Tam, I am not sure if we can use it for curl request ?

Comment: I think it is for rest api calls.

Comment: The main purpose of curl request is to make a http request. And the \Zend\Http\Request() class is suitable in this case.

Comment: ok then let me try

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done without extending the core Curl Class and its easy to extend though. Plz refer the below sample code.

**Extend the Core Curl Class**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl as CurlLibrary;

class Curl extends CurlLibrary
{
    /**
     * Make DELETE request
     *
     * The Magento Default curl library dosent support delete method
     *
     * @param string $uri
     * @return void
     */
    public function delete($uri)
    {
        $this->makeRequest("DELETE", $uri);
    }
}
```

**Then you can just call**

```
    use Company\Module\Model\Curl;

    public function __construct(
        Curl $curl,
    ) {
        $this->curl = $curl;
    }

   public function execute() {

    $this->curl->delete("delteURL")
  }
```